# Airflow celery executor with redis as broker and result backend produces too many redis connections

Tags: python, redis, celery, airflow

We are scheduling tasks with Airflow with celery as the executor, both of broker and result backend are redis. There are 200+ queues and 100+ workers, and the redis connections is 9200+ now, which is very close to the redis max connection threshold 10000.

I have tried 2 ways to reduce the redis connection but all of them not work well, the method that I have tried is:

1. set `ignore_result=True` in `@app.task()`, this method could reduce redis connection signicantly, but the task state in celery will be ignored, and the task could not be scheduled in Airflow if it is failed, since the scheduler could not get the info that the task in celery has failed.
2. set `BROKER_POOL_LIMIT=0`, this method could reduce redis connection a little, the redis connection of a queue that has no tasks run reduce from 10 to 8, after adding this config to airflow.cfg

I have upgrade celery from 4.0.2 to 4.1.0, but the problem is still there, is there any other way to solve this problem properly?